# How to get information about search results from / or ? (the contents of @/)

Tags: search

In normal mode with default mappings, suppose I type `/[,_@]`. This then causes all matches of that pattern to be highlighted. Is there some way to examine the results of this search? I am specifically interested in:

- the start and end positions of each match,
- the number of matches in the file,
- the number of matches between my cursor and the end of the file.

Is it possible to obtain this information, for use in further scripting?

If possible, I would like a solution that works without having to explicitly pass a filename, because I want it to be usable when editing text read from stdin or on a new buffer (as with `:enew`). This, as far as I can tell, disqualifies the use of `:vimgrep` which requires a filename.

I am aware of the `search()` function, but I'm not sure if it helps here.

Also, I use Neovim, so I will accept a Neovim-only solution.

Comment: You can get the number of matches with `:%s///n`. The rest will probably require a custom function.

Comment: @BLayer I clarified that I want to use the output for scripting, not just printing it.

Comment: Well, in that particular case you can capture in, say, a variable using `execute()`, e.g. `:let foo = execute('%s///n')` and likewise if you had a custom function. Or, for anything that outputs text you can use `redir` (`:h :redir`) to capture in a file, vim variable or register. I'll write that custom function if I get some time (if no one gets to it before me).

Comment: You should add some more details about capturing. The format you have in mind, for one. And how do you intend to use that in a script? Are you talking about another vim function(s)? Or some other scripting method?

Comment: BTW. Vim 8.2.0877+ has `:h searchcount()`. Maybe, it will be ported to Neovim... some day.